# Plotting a List with (0,0) as origin

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I have created a list which includes (0,0) in it but when plotted the plot is not joining the curve at (0,0). How to resolve this?

`l = Table[{b, \[Phi][b]}, {b, 0, 60}];ListLogPlot[l, PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 50}, {10^-4, 3}}]`

[image]

Comment: The scale on the y-axis is logarithmic, so it is impossible to plot any point with $y=0$

Comment: Then how to join the curve to x-axis?

Comment: Your definition of \[Phi] is missing, so your output cannot be reproduced by us.

Comment: @MadhurimaChakraborty you could use `ListPlot` instead. On a logarithmic scale, zero is "infinitely far" away from any finite value, so it is impossible to show in `ListLogPlot`